# Loading images from URLs into gridview

Tags: java, android, gridview

I have a gridview which is supposed to contain an image and a text below it. I am using Picasso to load the images but when I run the app, nothing appears in the imageviews! 
Below is my MainActivity.java code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    GridView gv;
    Context context;
    ArrayList prgmName;
    public static String [] prgmNameList={"C++","VB.NET","JAVA", "JavaScript", "MySQL", "PHP"};
    public static String [] prgmImgFiles = {"cpp.png", "vb.net.png", "java.png", "js.png", "mysql.png", "php.png"};
    public static Integer [] prgmImages={R.mipmap.img_0, R.mipmap.img_1, R.mipmap.img_2};
    public ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(prgmNameList));
    public ArrayList<Integer> arrayList2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(prgmImages));
    public ArrayList<String> arrayList3 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(prgmImgFiles));
    public static GridViewAdapter gvd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }

    public void onLoadClick(View v)
    {
        gv=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView2);
        gvd = new GridViewAdapter(this, arrayList, arrayList3);
        gv.setAdapter(gvd);

        ImageView iv2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewTest);

        // addItem("JavaScript", "http://10.0.2.2/picgal/images/js.png");
        Picasso.with(this).load("http://10.0.2.2/picgal/images/java.png").into(iv2);
    }

    public void addItem(String txt, String ImgID)
    {
        arrayList.add(txt);
        arrayList3.add(ImgID);
        gvd.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Below is my GridViewAdapter.java code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by ITM on 7/4/2016.
 */
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<String> result;
    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> imageId;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public static final String server = "http://10.0.2.2/picgal/images/";
    public Holder holder=new Holder();

    public GridViewAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, ArrayList<String> prgmNameList, ArrayList<String> prgmImages) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        result=prgmNameList;
        context=mainActivity;
        imageId=prgmImages;
        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return result.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder
    {
        public TextView tv;
        public ImageView img;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View rowView;

        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.img_layout, null);
        holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        holder.img=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);

        holder.tv.setText(result.get(position));
        Log.i("getView", imageId.get(position));
        Picasso.with(context).load(imageId.get(position)).into(holder.img);

        // holder.img.setImageResource(imageId.get(position));

        rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked " + result.get(position) +"\n"+getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

The activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.badihbarakat.gridviewapp.MainActivity">

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:id="@+id/gridView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#ffe5e5"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:scrollIndicators="left" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Load"
        android:id="@+id/btnLoad"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gridView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="onLoadClick" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewTest"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnLoad"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The img_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/frame" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have added a test ImageView below the button to test the Picasso object working. It is working fine. Can any one help please.
Thanks

Comment: given code is working fine.
I Have checked it Picasso object is working on my device. You have to replace http://10.0.2.2/picgal/images/ and http://10.0.2.2/picgal/images/java.png from  public static final String server = "http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/9d9b924594d34c669856ad4dcb7f0453.png"; which i use in my project

Comment: @Teekam the http://10.0.2.2/picgal/images is the location of the files on localhost on my laptop. The java.png loads ok when done individually like in the example above. But when run as part of the gridview adapter, it does not load any image in to the gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.You are passing wrong arguments in the gridView's constructor.

```
  gvd = new GridViewAdapter(this, arrayList, arrayList3);
```

should be

```
  gvd = new GridViewAdapter(this, arrayList, arrayList2);
```

as stated in your code, arrayList2 consists of Images.

2.In adapter, change the second argument in constructor:

```
 from ArrayList<String> to ArrayList<Integer>

 public GridViewAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, ArrayList<String> prgmNameList, ArrayList<Integer> prgmImages) {
    //...
```

}

After this, try passing it to Picasso.

New :
Can you try the following code :

```
      //server url
      String imageURL = ""
     //array of images passed in constructor to append with url
      String arrayOfImages[] = imageId;                                                                                                               
      String completeImageURL = server + arrayOfImages[position];
                Picasso.with(context)
                        .load(completeImageURL)
                        .into(holder.img);
```

Comment: But I do want to pass the arrayList3 which contains an array of the urls as strings. thats why the ArrayList<String>. I guess the text is correct. The other arrays are there since I was trying to use the mipmap. That works fine. But I want to use URLs.

Comment: @BadihBarakat Can you try the new snipped I have added in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

**Best ever I used , ImageLoader Library**

> https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView);
```

Comment: Do I have to download anything from github.com first?

Comment: what you using ? Android Studio or Eclipse ?

Comment: If you using Android Studio then use this compile link,
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
otherwise download jar file & use in eclipse.

Comment: I downloaded the ZIP file, and added the .jar files to the libs folder. They are there now but I need to figure out how to use it.

Comment: didn't work. May be I am missing something. But my question still is why the Picasso is not working when implemented in the gridview adapter!? but it works if used on static data?

Comment: if you using Android Studio then right click on jar file & select add as library option...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of you who assisted in this question. 
Actually, after revising the Picasso code, I discovered that the path to the image file was missing!
What I have put was:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(imageId.get(position)).into(holder.img);
```

As imageId.get(position) contains only the file name and not the full path on the server, the Picasso was not able to find the file!
The correct code is:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(server+imageId.get(position)).into(holder.img);
```

Where server is a String containing the full path of the images folder.
Thanks again to all of you.

Comment: As I should, as a concept, accept an answer, I will still accept the answer of "sha" as it was this comment which lead me to check the Picasso command code and discover the problem. :)